# Verify password hash in nodejs which was generated in php

Tags: php, node.js, security, bcrypt, php-password-hash

My php code generates a hash using `password_hash` which I store in a database. Below is the PHP code:

```
$hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));
```

I would like to verify / check the password against this hash in nodejs.

I saw lot of node modules (bcrypt, phpass, node-bcrypt), but all of them give me false. Below is sample hash generated in php and which I m trying to verify in nodejs.

```
var hash = '$2y$08$9TTThrthZhTOcoHELRjuN.3mJd2iKYIeNlV/CYJUWWRnDfRRw6fD2';

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

bcrypt.compare("secret", hash, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

(Here secret is real password)

My current workaround is to call a php script via node to verify (for anybody who needs a workaround)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'php verify.php password encryped_pasword';
exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  // output is in stdout
  console.log(stdout);
 //If stdout has 1 it satisfies else false
});
```

This is a hack and not a good answer to this problem. Is there a way to verify the password in nodejs without using a workaround like this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/bcrypt-nodejs

Comment: @o0rebelious0o I tried to compare using it, it gives null not even false and no error

Comment: beware, $cost must match to getRounds(), this is how bcrypt works.

Answer (score 68):

Replace $2y$ in the hashed password with $2a$，then bcrypt.compare should give you correct result.

```
var hash = '$2y$08$9TTThrthZhTOcoHELRjuN.3mJd2iKYIeNlV/CYJUWWRnDfRRw6fD2';
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
hash = hash.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, '$2a$1');
bcrypt.compare("secret", hash, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

on ES6:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
let hash = '$2y$08$9TTThrthZhTOcoHELRjuN.3mJd2iKYIeNlV/CYJUWWRnDfRRw6fD2';
hash = hash.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, '$2a$1');
bcrypt.compare('secret', hash, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: This helped me a lot thanks! Though would be interested to know why this is required if anyone knows?

Comment: Commenting to get updates on this (if any since it has been more than a year!)

Comment: I wish this was Medium and I could give this a few more well deserved upvotes

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `$2a$` or `$2y$` is only a prefix that indicates the version of the algorithm that's being used. In 2011 there was a major bug in the PHP implementation, and there was a initiative to change the original prefix `$2a$` to `$2x$` to indicate that the hash was done with the bugged algorithm and `$2y$` to indicate it was correct. No one but PHP took the recommendation. That's why node.js bcrypt doesn't recognize that prefix and PHP crypt_blowfish does.

Answer (score 33):

I know this has been answered, but it seems from the comments that a little more detail is required.

Bcrypt hashes produced by the php password_hash() function are split as follows:

`$2y$` `08$` `9TTThrthZhTOcoHELRjuN.` `3mJd2iKYIeNlV/CYJUWWRnDfRRw6fD2`

```
|     |     |                     |
|     |     Salt                  Hashed Password
|     |
|     Algorithm options (cost, in this case)
|
Algorithm type
```

It seems from other answers here on SO that while the PHP and Node versions of Bcrypt use different algorithms, the only difference in the hash output is the prefix. So all that is required is, as mentioned by @Sudesh, to swap the `$2y$` for a `$2a$` and Bob's your uncle.

**Sources**

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

[$2y bcrypt hashes in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041533/2y-bcrypt-hashes-in-node-js)

[Comparing BCrypt hash between PHP and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643587/comparing-bcrypt-hash-between-php-and-nodejs#26643637)