# password_hash equivalent in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, passwords

I'm facing a situation that need to verify password created via PHP `password_hash` method on nodejs server.

Does `nodejs` have an available package that equivalent to `password_hash` and `password_verify`? Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

In my case i created password in php like below

```
$data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

In Node if i want to verify that password than ...

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
params.hash = params.hash.replace('$2y$', '$2a$');
bcrypt.compare(params.password, params.hash,async function(err, correct) {
 console.log(correct);
});
```

Hope it will help you .....

Answer (score 4):

No, you will have to make use of one of the many Bcrypt libraries for Node.js.

P.S.: You're basically duplicating another user's question ([Verify password hash in nodejs which was generated in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015043/verify-password-hash-in-nodejs-which-was-generated-in-php)).