# Comparing BCrypt hash between PHP and NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, bcrypt

For an app I'm working on, nodejs needs to verify hashes created by PHP and vice-versa.

The problem is, the hashes generated in PHP (via Laravel's `Hash` class, which just uses PHP's `password_hash` function) return false when tested in node.js.

The following node.js script:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var password = 'password';

var phpGeneratedHash  = '$2y$10$jOTwkwLVn6OeA/843CyIHu67ib4RixMa/N/pTJVhOjTddvrG8ge5.';
var nodeGeneratedHash = '$2a$10$ZiBH5JtTDtXqDajO6f4EbeBIXGwtcGg2MGwr90xTH9ki34SV6rZhO';

console.log(
  bcrypt.compareSync(password, phpGeneratedHash)  ? 'PHP passed' : 'PHP failed',
  bcrypt.compareSync(password, nodeGeneratedHash) ? 'nodejs passed' : 'nodejs failed'
);
```

outputs: 'PHP failed nodejs passed', whereas the following PHP script:

```
<?php

$password = 'password';

$phpGeneratedHash  = '$2y$10$jOTwkwLVn6OeA/843CyIHu67ib4RixMa/N/pTJVhOjTddvrG8ge5.';
$nodeGeneratedHash = '$2a$10$ZiBH5JtTDtXqDajO6f4EbeBIXGwtcGg2MGwr90xTH9ki34SV6rZhO';

print password_verify($password, $phpGeneratedHash)  ? 'PHP passed' : 'PHP failed';
print password_verify($password, $nodeGeneratedHash) ? 'nodejs passed' : 'nodejs failed';
```

outputs 'PHP passed nodejs passed'.

I've run the tests in Ubuntu 14.04.1 using PHP 5.5.18, node.js v0.10.32 and the npm bcrypt module.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This fails because the types of bcrypt hashes being generated from php and node are different. Laravel generates the `$2y$` while node generates the `$2a$`. But the good news is the only difference between `2a` and `2y` are their prefixes.

So what you can do is make one of the prefix similar to the other. Like:

```
$phpGeneratedHash  = '$2y$10$jOTwkwLVn6OeA/843CyIHu67ib4RixMa/N/pTJVhOjTddvrG8ge5.';
$nodeGeneratedHash = '$2a$10$ZiBH5JtTDtXqDajO6f4EbeBIXGwtcGg2MGwr90xTH9ki34SV6rZhO';
```

To something like:

```
$phpGeneratedHash  = '$2y$10$jOTwkwLVn6OeA/843CyIHu67ib4RixMa/N/pTJVhOjTddvrG8ge5.';
$nodeGeneratedHash = '$2y$10$ZiBH5JtTDtXqDajO6f4EbeBIXGwtcGg2MGwr90xTH9ki34SV6rZhO';
```

Notice that I replaced the `$2a$` of the node hash to `$2y$`. You can simply do this with:

### PHP

```
$finalNodeGeneratedHash = str_replace("$2a$", "$2y$", $nodeGeneratedHash);
```

### Node

```
finalNodeGeneratedHash = nodeGeneratedHash.replace('$2a$', '$2y$');
```

Then compare `phpGeneratedHash` to `finalNodeGeneratedHash`.

> Note: It is recommended that if you're comparing in PHP, change the prefix of the NodeJS generated hash to `$2y$` and if you're comparing in NodeJS; change the prefix of the PHP generated hash to `$2a$`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, things are working as expected now! I hadn't thought to look up the structure of a bcrypt hash. Is there any obvious reason why the bcrypt module doesn't do what PHP is doing allowing either implementation to work?

Comment: @wolfemm, Simply, They are using different types/versions of bcrypt.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you.

I was pulling my hair out trying to get an [Auth0 Database Connection](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database) to [bcrypt.compareSync()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) a [Laravel password hash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing).

You saved my bacon, friendly Stack Overflow stranger.

Thank you.

Comment: ...2 years later. @JamesFurey you're welcome. I figured this out when I had to do the same thing which took awhile.

Comment: Thanks. This got me on the right track. And then `.replace(/^\$2y/, "$2a")` is what I ended up using... from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36043615/

Answer (score 7):

I have tried to compute what was said before to get codes that work. As you can see I don't need to replace anything.

On the PHP 7.2.4 side:

```
<?php
$password = "test123";
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    echo $hash; // I get $2y$10$5EaF4lMSCFWe7YqqxyBnR.QmDu1XhoiaQxrOFw.AJZkGCYmpsWDU6
```

On the nodeJS side:

Install bcryptjs package: npm i bcryptjs

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
let hash1="$2y$10$5EaF4lMSCFWe7YqqxyBnR.QmDu1XhoiaQxrOFw.AJZkGCYmpsWDU6";
console.log(bcrypt.compareSync("test123", hash1)); // display true
```

Comment: Could it be because you are using `bcryptjs` while the question uses `bcrypt` library

Comment: meanwhile bcryptjs has worse performance, look at the testing: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/node-js-bcrypt-vs-bcryptjs-benchmark-69a9e8254cc2

Comment: @MaximFirsoff That doesn't really matter. It's a one-time call on login/pw update, and the algorithm is slowed down on purpose (through repetitions) to resist attacks. Will a slow library help with that? Not really, as attacks will usually be on the raw userdata.... But it also doesn't really hurt.

(please note: I don't mean the bryptjs library is slow on purpose, it's just slower than the bcrypt library because its running in JS instead on natively)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of bcrypt in different language might be differ.

For example, in Node.js version [bcrypt.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js), the salt length applied are 29 characters

```
    bcrypt.getSalt = function(hash) {
        if (typeof hash !== 'string')
            throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof hash));
        if (hash.length !== 60)
            throw Error("Illegal hash length: "+hash.length+" != 60");
        return hash.substring(0, 29);
    };
```

But, in Go version [golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/bcrypt/bcrypt.go), the salt size are 22 of bytes:

```
const (
    majorVersion       = '2'
    minorVersion       = 'a'
    maxSaltSize        = 16
    maxCryptedHashSize = 23
    encodedSaltSize    = 22
    encodedHashSize    = 31
    minHashSize        = 59
)
```

So, it might happen that hashed string in Node.js gets error when compared in Go, other languages likewise.