# $2y bcrypt hashes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, bcrypt

I'm dealing with an old database with `$2y` hashes. I've dug into this a bit, also stumbled on [the stack overflow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20541/insecure-versions-of-crypt-hashes) on the difference between `$2a` and `$2y`.

I looked into the node module for [`bcrypt`](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js) which seems to generate and compare only `$2a` hashes.

- https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/175
- https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/349
- https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/213

I found a website that generates `$2y` hashes so I can test them with `bcrypt`.

- http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html

Here's an example of a `$2y` hash of the string `helloworld`.

```
helloworld:$2y$10$tRM7x9gGKhcAmpeqKEdhj.qRWCr4qoV1FU9se0Crx2hkMVNL2ktEW
```

Seems the module has no way of validating `$2y` hashes.

Here's my test.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var string = 'helloworld'

Promise.promisifyAll(bcrypt)

// bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
//   bcrypt.hash(string, salt, function(err, hash) {
//     console.log(hash)
//   })
// })

var hashesGeneratedUsingBcryptModule = [
  '$2a$10$6ppmIdlNEPwxWJskPaQ7l.d2fblh.GO6JomzrcpiD/hxGPOXA3Bsq',
  '$2a$10$YmpoYCDHzdAPMbd9B8l48.hkSnylnAPbOym367FKIEPa0ixY.o4b.',
  '$2a$10$Xfy3OPurrZEmbmmO0x1wGuFMdRTlmOgEMS0geg4wTj1vKcvXXjk06',
  '$2a$10$mYgwmdPZjiEncp7Yh5UB1uyPkoyavxrYcOIzzY4mzSniGpI9RbhL.',
  '$2a$10$dkBVTe2A2DAn24PUq1GZYe7AqL8WQqwOi8ZWBJAauOg60sk44DkOC'
]

var hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrg = [
  '$2y$10$MKgpAXLJkwx5tpijWX99Qek2gf/irwvp5iSfxuFoDswIjMIbj2.Ma',
  '$2y$10$tRM7x9gGKhcAmpeqKEdhj.qRWCr4qoV1FU9se0Crx2hkMVNL2ktEW'
]

var hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrgSwippedYForA = [
  '$2a$10$MKgpAXLJkwx5tpijWX99Qek2gf/irwvp5iSfxuFoDswIjMIbj2.Ma',
  '$2a$10$tRM7x9gGKhcAmpeqKEdhj.qRWCr4qoV1FU9se0Crx2hkMVNL2ktEW'
]

hashesGeneratedUsingBcryptModule = hashesGeneratedUsingBcryptModule.map(hash => bcrypt.compareAsync(string, hash))
hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrg = hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrg.map(hash => bcrypt.compareAsync(string, hash))
hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrgSwippedYForA = hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrgSwippedYForA.map(hash => bcrypt.compareAsync(string, hash))

Promise.all(hashesGeneratedUsingBcryptModule)
.tap(() => console.log('hashesGeneratedUsingBcryptModule'))
.then(console.log)

Promise.all(hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrg)
.tap(() => console.log('hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrg'))
.then(console.log)

Promise.all(hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrgSwippedYForA)
.tap(() => console.log('hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrgSwippedYForA'))
.then(console.log)
```

Here are the results:

```
// hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrg
// [ false, false ]
// hashesGeneratedUsingBcryptModule
// [ true, true, true, true, true ]
// hashesGeneratedUsingAspirineDotOrgSwippedYForA
// [ false, false ]
```

I'm stumped on how I can compare `$2y` hashes in node.

There's [another Stack Overflow question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643637/340688) that says you can just change the `$2y` to `$2a` but that still fails for me.

Update!

I was using [the generator](http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html) incorrectly because it's a `.htpasswd` password generator you have to put in the username and password in this format.

```
reggi helloworld
```

And the output corresponds here:

```
reggi:$2y$10$iuC7GYH/h1Gl1aDmcpLFpeJXN9OZXZUYnaqD2NnGLQiVGQYBDtbtO
```

Before I as putting just

```
helloword
```

Which I'm assuming hashed a empty string.

With these changes changing the `y` to an `a` works in `bcrypt`. And `twin-bcrypt` just works.

Comment: I vaguely recall having better luck working the other way -- taking the `$2a$` hashes generated by `bcrypt` in javascript, replacing `2a` with `2y`, and then comparing using `2y` libraries in other languages (php natively and `BCrypt` from .net could both handle it, which struck me as very odd). I can dig up the test code I had, if that would be helpful to you.

Comment: @dvlsg Got it. That makes sense. So I need to compare `$2y` hashes in node, not `$2a` hashes in php, which I'm guessing works by replacing the `a` to `y`.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually storing the hashes as `$2y` in the database, using them as-is for both PHP and .NET, but when I used them in node I had an extra convert step which swapped `y` back to `a` before comparison. It felt wrong, but it looked like `2a` and `2y` used the same structure for the rest of the salt/hash.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- When using `bcrypt` change the `y` to an `a`.
- When using `twin-bcrypt` the hash just works.

When using http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html make sure that you provide a username and password.

```
reggi helloworld
```

Then:

```
reggi:$2y$10$Am0Nf/B6.S/Wkpr6IVdIZeuHWNa/fqoLyTNmlyrSg22AjRf2vS.T.
```

Here's a working example with both `bcrypt` and `twin-bcrypt`.

```
var twinBcrypt = require('twin-bcrypt')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var string = 'helloworld'

var bcryptAttempt = bcrypt.compareSync(string, "$2y$10$Am0Nf/B6.S/Wkpr6IVdIZeuHWNa/fqoLyTNmlyrSg22AjRf2vS.T.".replace(/^\$2y/, "$2a"))
console.log(bcryptAttempt)

var twinBcryptAttempt = twinBcrypt.compareSync(string, "$2y$10$Am0Nf/B6.S/Wkpr6IVdIZeuHWNa/fqoLyTNmlyrSg22AjRf2vS.T.")
console.log(twinBcryptAttempt)
```

Outputs:

```
true
true
```

Comment: you mean false, true?

Comment: 2 years later and still this is a life saver!