# NodeJS Bcrypt returns false when comparing hashed password from Invision Community

Tags: node.js

I have a forum which is running Invision Community and I'm building an API using Express.JS and Prisma to query the database.

When I do a POST request with my username and password (all info sent are correct) and I extract the hashed password from the database to compare but I always get back false.

I do like this:

```js
const isValid = await bcrypt.compare("Test123123", "$2y$10$IPu20eKbJ1I7WcsWnuSq1u9NlcYhVRgdUWSHoENNH2fguhca8K2py")
```

Any ideas on why I always get back false?

Comment: 1. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041533/2y-bcrypt-hashes-in-node-js / 2. Is that other software using a global hash salt, also known as "pepper"?

Comment: @RobertKawecki Thank you, that post solved my issue. When I use: ``twin-bcrypt`` it works fine!