# Decrypt Laravel user password in Node API (using becrypt package) is not working

Tags: node.js, laravel, authentication, bcrypt

I have a **Laravel** existing project where they use Laravel default encryption (i.e **Hash::make('')**) for user registration,so in database they saved the data with this encryption format.

Now I am creating **API's using Node** for the same MySQL database.So for those password decryption I have used Node **bcrypt** package.But the decryption is not working and I am getting error for JWT authentication token.I have used "algorithm": "**RS256**" for this Node API.So can anyone tell me if I did something wrong or I have to choose another package(in node) or any other algorithm(in node).

I think that is becrypt. Now when I am creating the API's with Node I have used Node be

Comment: hashing is not encryption, you can't turn the hashed password back into the plain text version ... you have to use what ever facility there is to do a hash check

Comment: Laravel has both encryption/decryption and hashing logic available. I hope your passwords are using hashing, otherwise you have a serious security vulnerability. But as stated, hashing is a one-way function; you can't unhash something to see the plain-text equivalent. You can only generate a hash and compare it to an existing hash to see if it's the same.

Comment: You should check the hash to see if it matches with password. Using node bcrypt package, it seems you need this: // Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
    // res == true
});

Comment: I don't want the hashed password give me a plain text version .I just asked why the bcrypt.compare is not working in my Node API (if laravel use bcrypt or HASH). @Hamid I did the same thing but don't know what is wrong ? is this only package in node is bcrypt right ?

Comment: Did u find any solution  ?

Answer (score 1):

Passwords in Laravel are hashed, which is different to encrypt them, because Hash is not reversible, when encryption can be reversed.

Furthermore, in order to let Node be able to decrypt encrypted data, you should share with Node the key that Laravel has used to encrypt that data, and that's **absolutely very dangerous**, because everyone than can have that key, and so if he finds a breach in you sql, like a possibility to run SQL injection, than he can use that key to decrypt that data

Comment: luckily they are not dealing with encryption :)

Comment: @Alberto thanks for your contribute. I need to know why the bcrypt.compare is not working in my Node API .is there any other package to compare this password

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I’ve missunderstood the question... so, you have 2 project, one PHP Laravel and the second one Node js for the api, right? And you are saying that the Node api can’t decrypt some information from the database which was previously encrypted by Laravel right? So what I can suggest you is to first of all, check the compatibility for the node version to the Laravel encryption version, second, to check if the key set on Node is the same as the key set on the .env under APP_KEY on your Laravel project

Comment: With check compatibility, I mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643587/comparing-bcrypt-hash-between-php-and-nodejs