# Password(+salt) hashing and verifying in PHP and/or NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js

I use in php the following code to generate a password hash and a salt.

```
$salt = password_hash(uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
password_hash($password . $salt, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

I am using `bcrypt`in NodeJS and want to achieve to verify the password in NodeJS.
I save the hash and the password salt in my database and can query this in my NodeJS application.

After a few researching tries, I found this post on SO:
[Verify password hash in nodejs which was generated in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015043/verify-password-hash-in-nodejs-which-was-generated-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Now I added the replace part to my code.

My pseudo:

```
bcrypt.compare(password_from_input + salt_from_db.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, '\$2a$1'), password_from_db.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, '\$2a$1'), function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

And I also want it the other way around. So create a salt and hash in NodeJS and verify in PHP.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: You don't need to add the salt to the input password in `bcrypt.compare()`.

Comment: If I hash the password in PHP without a salt, the compare in NodeJS works.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. Why do you hash the random salt in PHP? Why are you adding a salt at all?

Comment: I someway read that it would be way more secure if I add a salt. So I don't have to add a salt, right?

Comment: You need a salt, but `password_hash()` generates one automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hash a password in PHP:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

This generates a hash with `$2y$` that you need to store in the database. Use this code to compare the password in Node:

```
bcrypt.compare(password_from_input, password_from_db.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, '\$2a$1'), function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

To hash a password in Node:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(password_from_input, salt, function(err, hash) {
        hash = hash.replace(/^\$2a(.+)$/i, '\$2y$1');
        //Insert into database
    });
});
```

This generates a hash with `$2a$`. The example above replaces it with `$2y$`, so comparing will be easier in PHP.

To compare a password in PHP:

```
if (password_verify($password_from_input, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```