# NODE.JS - How to check a Laravel hashed password with bcrypt?

Tags: node.js, laravel, hash, bcrypt

I'm developing a `Node.js` application that needs to log in using the same database information from a `Laravel` aplication.

I've read about `BCrypt` and trying to use it to make a comparison of the hashed password it generates with the `Laravel` one stored in the database.

So, by the documentation of `BCrypt`, I need to do something like that:

```
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(myPlaintextPassword, salt);
```

But I have no idead on how to use the exact same salt from `Laravel` to hash my password. I need to use the **APP_KEY** to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I fond the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015043/verify-password-hash-in-nodejs-which-was-generated-in-php). It's way easier than I thought.

```
var hash = '$2y$08$9TTThrthZhTOcoHELRjuN.3mJd2iKYIeNlV/CYJUWWRnDfRRw6fD2';
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
hash = hash.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, '$2a$1');
bcrypt.compare("secret", hash, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for solving a problem, coming back, and sharing it!

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, the salt is stored as part of the hash.

So why not just compare a plain text against the stored hash.

Try the following (from bcrypt docs) :

```
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
    // res == true
});
```

`hash` would be the users password hash value in the `Laravel` database.

for example :

```
var pass_hash = '$2y$12$Z3Dk1YAzNsdXxq8EKNQxluqGglI6dvncfJxDj0mZHh7zceX2XoX/W'
var pass_string = '1234'
bcrypt.compare(pass_string, pass_hash,(err,valid)=>{
 if(valid){console.log("valid password match")}
 else{console.log("wrong credentials")}
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The `compare`always return "wrong credentials".

Comment: Are you sure you have the valid match for the specific hash?

Comment: Yes. I've made the password using **Hash::make** from Laravel and I know for sure what the password without hash is.

Comment: if you console.log the pass_hash before comparing does it show the one from the database? (just making sure you are not comparing something wrong or an undefined value)... If you test my example, hard-coding the pass_hash and the pass_string, does it work?