# Read cookies in Laravel Blade created in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am beginner webdeveloper. I make my project in Laravel 7 and jQuery.

I create cookies in JavaScript (jQuery) and I need read it in Laravel Blade.

I have this code:

```
!function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=t():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(t):(e=e||self,function(){var r=e.Cookies,n=e.Cookies=t();n.noConflict=function(){return e.Cookies=r,n}}())}(this,function(){"use strict";function e(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var r=arguments[t];for(var n in r)e[n]=r[n]}return e}var t={read:function(e){return e.replace(/%3B/g,";")},write:function(e){return e.replace(/;/g,"%3B")}};return function r(n,i){function o(r,o,u){if("undefined"!=typeof document){"number"==typeof(u=e({},i,u)).expires&&(u.expires=new Date(Date.now()+864e5*u.expires)),u.expires&&(u.expires=u.expires.toUTCString()),r=t.write(r).replace(/=/g,"%3D"),o=n.write(String(o),r);var c="";for(var f in u)u[f]&&(c+="; "+f,!0!==u[f]&&(c+="="+u[f].split(";")[0]));return document.cookie=r+"="+o+c}}return Object.create({set:o,get:function(e){if("undefined"!=typeof document&&(!arguments.length||e)){for(var r=document.cookie?document.cookie.split("; "):[],i={},o=0;o<r.length;o++){var u=r[o].split("="),c=u.slice(1).join("="),f=t.read(u[0]).replace(/%3D/g,"=");if(i[f]=n.read(c,f),e===f)break}return e?i[e]:i}},remove:function(t,r){o(t,"",e({},r,{expires:-1}))},withAttributes:function(t){return r(this.converter,e({},this.attributes,t))},withConverter:function(t){return r(e({},this.converter,t),this.attributes)}},{attributes:{value:Object.freeze(i)},converter:{value:Object.freeze(n)}})}(t,{path:"/"})});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cookies-box-close').click(function (e) {
        $('.cookies-box').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.cookies-box').addClass('d-none');
        Cookies.set('hiddenCookiesSplash', '1', { expires: 30 })
    });

});
```

This code create cookies correctly.

Now I try check value in Laravel Blade:

```
@if (Cookie::get('hiddenCookiesSplash') != '1')
Is okey
@endif
```

But it's not working - laravel can't read vale from cookie :(

How can I repair it?

Comment: PHP is processed server side, whereas the js is run in your browser. The PHP code is run before your script is.

Comment: Yes, Blade is a templating engine on server side. Once it is loaded to the browser, it is all Javascript to deal with interaction. So instead of creating cookies, and check it, you need to use JS to handle the show/hide logic of the DOM

Comment: Yes, but I create cookies in JS. Now I need read it in php (blade)

Comment: @trzew That is not possible. The PHP code is evaluated before the JS ever runs in a user's browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you should keep in mind that by default Laravel can only read cookies set by Laravel.

The Laravel automatically encrypts all cookies with Bcrypt. You can do one of the following:

1. Use Laravel backend to create your cookies. *(Recommended)*
2. Encrypt your cookie value with Bcrypt in order to Laravel read them.
3. Disable Laravel cookie encryption, which should allow your Laravel application to read cookies from all sources. *(Not recommended)*

**Sources:**

[1. Using Laravel to create cookies](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses)

[2. Reading Laravel Bcrypt within Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656617/node-js-how-to-check-a-laravel-hashed-password-with-bcrypt)

[3. How to disabled Laravel Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578508/12423305)

Comment: You can also just disable encryption for asingle field https://stackoverflow.com/a/35038604/2311074